# Sync css translation of scrolling text to same speed (but different duration)

Tags: css, angular, css-animations

I have prepared a StackBlitz application (angular) to showcase my issue.

[Application](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9wdc4g?file=src/app/app.component.html)

As you can see, the texts are moving at different speeds due to different text lengths.
What I would like is to dynamically set the duration so all text animations have the same scroll speed. My current calculation is missing something (or perhaps is way off?) but I'm having trouble figuring it out. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. GetDuration now looks like this:

```
getDuration(el: any) {
    const scrollInterval = 25;
    const scrollSpacePx = 1;
    const speed = scrollSpacePx / scrollInterval;
    const durationMs = (el.clientWidth + el.parentElement.clientWidth) / speed;
    const durationSec = durationMs / 1000;

    return durationSec.toString() + "s";
  }
```